# How do I select values from a table between the current date and a fixed date each year?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

In my program I have a table that holds details about jobs entered and the amount earned from them.

I should be able to select the amounts from jobs whose **`DATEBANK`** lies between the current date and a fixed date each year: The start of the financial year.

```
c.execute("SELECT AMOUNT FROM vatsum1 WHERE DATEBANK BETWEEN '{x}' AND '{y}'".\
                    format(y = DateBankCur, x = StrtFYear))
```

I have managed to get the current date fine and the start of financial year for a specific year (e.g 01/02/2016) .

But this won't hold up when I am using dates from later or previous years.

How can I pick the most recent "01/02" to compare the current date to?

Comment: What is your date format? Is it string 'MM/DD/YYYY'?

Comment: No it's a datetime object in the format: YYYY-MM-DD. I have already done some date operations successfully. I just don't know how to select amounts between the current date and the start of the financial year.

Comment: I can't quite understand. Looks like you want to select amounts between a _date you chose_ and the start of the financial year corresponding to _chosen date_. Am I right?

Comment: Are you looking for something different from "generate the desired date in the current year, then if it's in the future, subtract a year"?

Answer (score 0):

If `StrtFYear` is an integer representing a year, you can select all records whose `DATEBANK` has a year greater than or equal to that year by using

```
strftime('%Y', DATEBANK) >= ?
```

---

For example,

```
import datetime as DT
StrtFYear = 2015
DateBankCur = DT.date.today()
c.execute(
    "SELECT AMOUNT FROM vatsum1 WHERE strftime('%Y', DATEBANK) >= ? AND DATEBANK <= ?", 
    (StrtFYear, DateBankCur))
```

---

Note that it is easier and safer to supply the arguments, `(StrtFYear, DateBankCur)` as the second argument to `c.execute` rather than trying to quoting the arguments using string formatting yourself. It is safer because it is not vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

---

If `StrtFYear` is a Python `datetime.date`, then you can obtain the integer year using `StrtFYear.year`. In that case you could use

```
c.execute(
    "SELECT AMOUNT FROM vatsum1 WHERE strftime('%Y', DATEBANK) >= ? AND DATEBANK <= ?", 
    (StrtFYear.year, DateBankCur))
```

Comment: I don't think SQLite has a `YEAR()` function.

Comment: @glibdud: Thanks for the correction. I've replaced it with [`strftime('%Y', DATEBANK)`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).